# Autoload folder without changing composer.json file - Laravel 5.4

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.4, composer-php

I've created a package that creates a folder in the root of the project.
Creating it in the app folder is for me not clean enough. Cause I don't want it to look like it's merged with the laravel framework.
This package is for our company and will be used a lot.

So instead of changing the composer.json file everytime to add the folder to the autoloader I'm trying to just autoload it from the package.

Is something like that possible and how?

Comment: For people downvoting, please explain what you don't understand about the question so I can edit it.

Answer (score 0):

Are you saying that you **do not** want to add it in your `composer.json` file here?

```
"autoload": {
    "classmap": [
        "database"
    ],
    "psr-4": {
        "App\\": "app/",
        "Company\\": "company/"
    }
},
```

That is what I would do.

---

What if you just use the folder structure as the autoloader namespace? That should work. For example:

```
<?php

use Company\Foo;

new Bar();
```

Where you would have a folder called `company/Foo` with all the classes inside declaring their namespace like so:

```
<?php

namespace Company\Foo;

class Bar {
    //
}
```

Comment: This is the thing I don't want to. Can I autoload the company folder from my package, with either the package's composer file, or some piece of code? That's my question :)